# Build KML branch of cesium

Tags: node.js, git, kml, cesiumjs

I am trying to install the kml branch of Cesium on my local windows machine and I am following instructions to install it from https://github.com/AnalyticalGraphicsInc/cesium/wiki/Contributor's-Guide. I have jdk1.8 installed and node.js installed on my system. I am new to node.js. When I try to build the code I am getting following message. What am I missing in this?

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\cesium-kmz>.\Tools\apache-ant-1.8.2\bin\ant combine runServer
Buildfile: C:\xampp\htdocs\cesium-kmz\build.xml

build:

checkForNode:
 [exec] Execute failed: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "node": Crea
teProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified

BUILD FAILED
C:\xampp\htdocs\cesium-kmz\build.xml:296: Node.js is required to run this part of the build.  Install from http://nodejs.org/

Total time: 3 seconds
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the `node` executable is not in your PATH.  Did you select that option at Node install time?  Also, did you run `npm install` successfully before running `ant`?